# How to query for a Customer that has orders of a certain type OR no orders at all?

Tags: java, jpa, select, left-join, jpql

I know how to query for Customers with certain type of Orders (after joining the Orders with leftjoinfetch):

```
select c from Customer c where c.orders.type = 'CANCELLED'
```

I also know how to query for Customers with no Orders at all:

```
select c from Customer c where c.orders is empty
```

**How can I, in one query, select all the Customers with certain type of Orders OR no Orders at all?**

Thank you.

Comment: I cannot see any left join fetch you have used anywhere in the statements shown. Also `c.orders.type` will produce a cartesian product (cross join) on certain JPA providers like Hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

Something like (in the absence of the actual entities).

```
SELECT c FROM Customer c LEFT JOIN c.orders o WHERE c.orders IS EMPTY OR o.type = 'CANCELLED'
```